# VPN service in mobile apps

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, vpn

I am coding in c# and using Xamarin and Visual studios in creating an Android app.  I am trying to find a VPN API that allows me to connect to a VPN using user authentication.  I am using Auth0 to create the user authentication process and would like to use that username and password to be sent to the VPN as its "negotiation" to be allowed in the tunnel.

So far I have looked into OpenVPN, ToyVpn and VpnService and haven't seen a method of being able to send over a username and password with these samples they provide (they just provide ways to send over server addresses it seems).  I also looked into DotRas and that seems to only apply for web apps and not mobile apps.  If I am mistaken and there are ways to do this then please provide sample code that shows this.

Right now we use Anyconnect from Cisco as a separate app that works around this issue.  But we want to be more user friendly and not have to force clients to get a separate app for that and want it included in our app.

So does anyone know an API that can handle connecting to a VPN and sending over the User info?

Comment: AnyConnect does support URIs to automate connections... it is really limited, but it helps... http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect30/administration/guide/anyconnectadmin30/acmobiledevices.html#pgfId-1011562

Comment: Ok I will see if I can figure that out thanks!

Comment: Dang apparently I need a paid account to download that API, bummer.  I might be able to find someone who does though.  If anyone else knows a free version in the meantime please share.